# Search for multiple strings in vba

Tags: excel, vba

so basically i needed to create a macro that needs to compare lots of cells that contain many different strings. What i had already have is like this:

```
Sub strcom()
Dim r as range ‘dt_range is a named range in name manager
For r in range(“dt_range”)
If instr(“ab”, r.value,1) then ...
If instr(“cd”, r.value, 1) then ...
...
Next r
...
End sub
```

If i am gonna do this its gonna be very inefficient because i have lots of strings to be compared with, are there any better methods instead of doing this? I wanted to use the select case but not sure how it’s gonna work.

Comment: Is the action different for each ***Then***  .........??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select Case` gives really small advantage over `If-Else`. However, this is a way to do it:

```
Sub StrCom()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim dtRange As Range

    Set dtRange = Range("A1:Z10")

    For Each r In dtRange

        Select Case True

        Case InStr(1, "ab", r)

        Case InStr(1, "cd", r)

        Case Else

        End Select

    Next r
End Sub
```

Another option is to use 2 nested loops, looping from the cells and from the values to be checked. Something like this:

```
Sub StrCom()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim dtRange As Range

    Set dtRange = Range("A1:Z10")
    Dim someArray As Variant

    someArray = Array("ab", "cd", "ef")
    Dim arrVal As Variant

    For Each r In dtRange
        For Each arrVal In someArray
            If InStr(1, arrVal, r) Then
                'do something
            End If
        Next arrVal
    Next r

End Sub
```